# PDF editor to highlight text on Lubuntu

Tags: pdf, software-rec, lubuntu, highlighting

I would need a PDF editor that works well on Lubuntu to highlight some sections of a PDF and save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

[Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) and [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) both have the ability to do what you need and should be available in your repositories.